# Sending data from ajax to controller in C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an object in javascript with LocationId and id.

I have a class MyClass in C# with those two variables.

I have an ajax call which calls a method in my controller:

```
MyMethod(List<MyClass> myObject, int user_id)
```

I use:

```
traditional: true
```

in the ajax call.

The method gets called, myObject has the correct length, but LocationId and id are all 0. Why is this happening and how to solve it?

```
public class MyClass {
     public int LocationId {get; set;}
     public int id {get; set;}
}
```

Javascript:

```
var myArray = new Array();
var object = new {
    LocationId: 1;
    id: 2;
}
myArray.push(object);
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "correctUrl",
    traditional: true,
    data: { user_id: 1, myObject: myArray}
});
```

Comment: Your C# code would not even compile. You can't have semicolons after property declaration.

Comment: I think you are missing content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Javascript code to create the object is invalid. Try this:

```
var myArray = new Array();
var object = {       // No new
    LocationId: 1,   // , instead of ;
    id: 2
}
myArray.push(object);
```

By the way, you could shorten this to:

```
var myArray = [ { LocationId: 1, id: 2 } ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex.
I would change your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
    url: "correctUrl",
    data: JSON.stringify( {user_id: 1, myObject: myArray} ),
    // traditional: true,
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

I've removed `traditional: true` you don't need it here.
Changed the submission type to POST. It works better with serialized object.
I've transformed the submitted data with **JSON.stringify**

You can download **json2.js** [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

I've changed your C# class this way:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class jSonObject
{
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> myObject { get; set; }
}
```

and your MVC action should look like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyMethod(jSonObject myData)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Another thing I would suggest is to implement a **JsonValueProviderFactory**.
You can find lot of useful information [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonvalueproviderfactory%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).